# Registering a health check with consul in C#

Tags: c#, consul

Using dotnet client for Consult, not much documentation on the API's but followed the [Unit Tests](https://github.com/PlayFab/consuldotnet/blob/master/Consul.Test/AgentTest.cs).

How do I specify Check settings that keeps checking the health status of this registered microservice?

```
using (var consul = new ConsulClient(configuration => configuration.Address = new Uri("http://localhost:8500")))
{
    var registration = new AgentServiceRegistration
    {
        ID = "customer",
        Name = "customer",
        Address = Dns.GetHostName(),
        Port = 80
    };

    consul.Agent.ServiceDeregister(registration.ID).Wait();
    consul.Agent.ServiceRegister(registration).Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("Registered with Consul.");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add checks at registration

```
using (var consul = new ConsulClient(configuration => configuration.Address = new Uri("http://localhost:8500")))
{
    var registration = new AgentServiceRegistration
    {
        ID = "customer",
        Name = "customer",
        Address = Dns.GetHostName(),
        Port = 80
        //at your check code here
        Check = new AgentServiceCheck()
                {
                    HTTP = "http://yourUrl.com",
                    Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
                },
    };

    consul.Agent.ServiceDeregister(registration.ID).Wait();
    consul.Agent.ServiceRegister(registration).Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("Registered with Consul.");
}
```

Now you can find your checks in the node section of the consul.ui.